# Fullcalendar is duplicating event on drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My fullcalendar duplicates events visually when i drag them to another timeslot. I have simplified my code down to the eventDrop to isolate the issue and yet I'm unable to understand the issue.
If I store the events to my localStorage I don't get a duplicate in the storage and the duplicate disappears when I reload the page. This means the problem is only visual and with Full Calendar itself.
However, this is obviously a huge issue as I don't want to reload the page: I want to stay in the current view changing what I need.

Here's my code for the eventDrop:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to change " + event.title + " ?")) {
                    /*If the user cancels the change, the event returns to its original position. Otherwise it saves the event.*/

                    revertFunc();       /*Revert changes using the predefined function revertFunc of fullCalendar.*/

                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                    /*FullCalendar Method to refetch events from all sources and rerender them on the screen.*/

                } else {

                    updateConfirm(event);       /*Use the logic to confirm the event update properties*/

                    Evento.prototype.Update(event);     /*Modify the targeted event on the localStorage using the Update method of the Evento Class*/

                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", event);
                    /*FullCalendar Method to report changes to an event and render them on the calendar.*/

                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                    /*FullCalendar Method to refetch events from all sources and rerender them on the screen.*/

                }
            }
```

And here's a gif of the issue:
https://i.imgur.com/rFPvvjE.gif

UPDATE: With slicedtoad's help I isolated the issue to my updateConfirm logic:

```
var updateConfirm = function(event) {
    if (confirm("New title?")) {    /*Check if the user wants to change the event title*/
        event.title = prompt("Enter the new title: ");    /*Set new title for the event*/
    } else {
        event.title = event.title;
    }

    if (confirm("New description?")) {    /*Check if the user wants to change the event description*/
        event.description = prompt("Enter the new description: ");    /*Set new description for the event*/
    } else {
        event.description = event.description;
    }

    if (confirm("Is the event important?")) {   /*Check if the user wants to change the event priority*/
        event.overlap = false;
        event.backgroundColor = "red";    /*Set new priority for the event*/
    } else {
        event.overlap = true;
        event.backgroundColor = "blue";   /*Set new priority for the event*/
    }
};
```

UPDATE 2:
`console.log(event)` **before** updateConfirm(event):

```
Object {id: "2015-01-27T15:29:11+00:00", title: "título", start: m, end: m, allDay: false…}_allDay: false_end: m_id: "2015-01-27T15:29:11+00:00"_start: mallDay: falsebackgroundColor: "blue"className: Array[0]description: "gt4"end: mid: "2015-01-27T15:29:11+00:00"overlap: truesource: Objectstart: mstoringId: "2015-01-27T15:29:11+00:00"title: "título"__proto__: Object
```

`console.log(event)` **after** updateConfirm(event):

```
Object {id: "2015-01-27T15:29:11+00:00", title: "título", start: m, end: m, allDay: false…}_allDay: false_end: m_id: "2015-01-27T15:29:11+00:00"_start: mallDay: falsebackgroundColor: "blue"className: Array[0]description: "gt4"end: mid: "2015-01-27T15:29:11+00:00"overlap: truesource: Objectstart: mstoringId: "2015-01-27T15:29:11+00:00"title: "título"__proto__: Object
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/rFPvvjE.gif no longer works... :(

Answer (score 1):

Since the event is not locally sourced, calling `updateEvent` isn't necessary since the event will be refetched from the database when you call `$("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");`

I'm not entirely sure why it would duplicate but the event modified by `updateEvent` seems to persist past the refetch. You must be changing it's ID or replacing it with another event object, but I wasn't able to reproduce it.

So try removing the update line

```
} else {
    updateConfirm(event); 
    Evento.prototype.Update(event);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
}
```

If that doesn't work, try deleting the event manually:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', event._id ) //replace the updateEvent call with this
//or event.id if your events have an explicit id
```

**Addendum**

You likely want to actually figure out the cause of the problem since the above just patches it. Something in <strike>`Evento.prototype.Update`</strike> `updateConfirm` is modifying the event to the point that FC thinks it is a different event. Is it being copied and replacing itself? Are you playing with it's id?

Comment: Hmm. I was able to isolate it with your answer... it's my updateConfirm logic that is wrong.

I'm updating the question with that code.

Comment: @mesosteros Wrong as in it made bad changes to the event?

Comment: The updateConfirm simply checks if a user wants to change the event title, description, if it is an allday event, etc...
I added the logic code.

Comment: @mesosteros I still can't reproduce the problem. This should be simulating what you're doing http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/xkmx8sgp/3/

Comment: I've nailed it further down. It's the prompt. The first one to be precise (event.title = prompt("Enter the new title: ");)
It gets two event objects inside... although I'm dumbfounded as to the why. Never seen this behavious before.

Comment: can you do a `console.log(event)` before and after `updateConfirm(event)` and post the objects? Cause the problem isn't happening for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do singleton style solution:

This worked for me to stop the duplication which was caused by "new Draggable(container)"
every time reloaded the view

```
$scope.Draggable = null  if ($scope.Draggable == null) {
                $scope.Draggable = new Draggable(containerEl, {
                    itemSelector: '.item',
                    eventData: function (eventEl) {
                        return {
                            title: eventEl.innerText
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
```